# Firefox CSS issue with HTML table

Tags: css, firefox, layout

I am new to coding and have hit my first bump in the road. I have been searching for two days now for the answer and so far from what I am seeing I am not the only one, however I have tried using or adding some of the techniques I have seen people used and at this point I am stumped.

My issue occurs only within firefox and displays perfectly fine in IE and Chrome. I have created a comparison chart and my table seems to get pushed upwards misaligning all the cells. I have tried changing the width to 100%, I am using a CSS reset so padding and margin are set to zero from the start, and I have also tried border-spacing. Please help I have attached my code below and I have a screen shot but cannot attach as I am new.

I am using firefox version 15.0 on a windows 7 OS

peice of my HTML I can add more needed

```
<div id="tblCenter">
            <table class="contItems">
            <tr>
            <td class="yes"><div class="row1"></div></td>

            <td class="yes"><div class="row2"></div></td>
            <td class="yes"><div class="row1"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="yes"><div class="row1"></div></td>
            <td class="yes"><div class="row2"></div></td>
            <td class="yes"><div class="row1"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="yes"><div class="row1"></div></td>
            <td class="yes"><div class="row2"></div></td>
            <td class="yes"><div class="row1"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="yes"><div class="row1"></div></td>
            <td class="yes"><div class="row2"></div></td>
            <td class="yes"><div class="row1"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

CSS for the table and design part of my page

`               @charset "utf-8";
                /* CSS Document */

```
            #seoBox{
                width: 950px;
                margin: auto;
                padding: 0px;
            `enter code here`}
            #seoContent{
                margin: 25px 10px 25px 5px;
            }
            #seoContent h1 p tr td{
                font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                color:#000000;
            }
            #seoContent p{
                padding: 0 0 10px 0;
            }
            #seoContent #bulletPoint{
                width: 500px;
                padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
            }
            #seoContent #bulletPoint ul{
                display: block;
                list-style-type:none; 
            }

            #bulletPoint li{
                background: url(../styleImages/Star.png) top left no-repeat ;
                padding: 0 0 7px 25px;
            }
            #packages{
                width: 935px
            }
            #sideBar{
                width: 190px;
                float: left;
                margin-top: 92px;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #sideBar td{
                height: 25px;
                padding: 8px 0 0 0;
                background: url(../styleImages/tbl_line_lght.png) bottom left no-repeat;
            }
            #mainTbl{
                width: 664px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #mainTbl .contItems{
                border-collapse:collapse;
                margin-top: 0px;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            .contItems td{
                width: 220px;
                height: 25px;
                padding-top: 8px;
            }
            .row1{
                width: 167;
                height: 3px;
                background:url(../styleImages/tbl_line_lght.png) no-repeat;
                position: relative;
                bottom: -12px;
                left: 20px;
                }
            .textR1{
                width: 167;
                height: 3px;
                background:url(../styleImages/tbl_line_lght.png) no-repeat;
                position: relative;
                bottom: -20px;
                left: 20px;
            }
            .row2{
                width: 167;
                height: 3px;
                background: url(../styleImages/tbl_linedrk.png) no-repeat;
                position: relative;
                bottom: -12px;
                left: 20px;

            }
            .textR2{
                width: 167;
                height: 3px;
                background:url(../styleImages/tbl_linedrk.png) no-repeat;
                position: relative;
                bottom: -20px;
                left: 20px;
            }
            .contItems .yes{
                text-align: center;
                background: url(../styleImages/green_yes.png) center center no-repeat;
            }
            .contItems .no{
                text-align: center;
                background: url(../styleImages/red_no.png) center center no-repeat;
            }
            #packbg{
                width: 730px;
                height: 1100px;
                background: url(../styleImages/tblbg.png) top left repeat-x;
                float:left;
                margin-bottom: 50px;
            }
            #tblTop, #tblCenter, #tblRibbon, #tblBottom{
                margin-left: 25px;
            }
            #tblTitle{
                width: 535px;
                height: 50px;
                margin-left: 80px;
                background: url(../styleImages/Tbl_title.png) bottom left no-repeat;
            }
            #tblTop{
                width: 665px;
                height: 40px;
                background: url(../styleImages/tbl_top.png) no-repeat top left;

            }
            #tblCenter{
                width: 665px;
                height: 910px;
                background: url(../styleImages/tbl_center.png) repeat-y top left;
            }
            #buyButton {
                margin-left: 35px;
                width:650px;
                height: 42px;
            }
            .buyNow{
                width: 121px;
                height: 42px;
                background: url(../styleImages/Buy_Now.jpg) top center no-repeat;
                border: 0px;
                margin: 0 45px;
            }
            #tblRibbon{
                width: 650px;
                height: 65px;
                background: url(../styleImages/Ribbon.png) no-repeat;
                position: relative;
                top: -140px;
                left: 8px;
            }
            #tblBottom{
                width: 665px;
                height: 33px;
                background: url(../styleImages/tbl_bottom.png) no-repeat top left;
            }
            /* end Table CSS */
```

Comment: Could you post a working example to JSFiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: This `<div id="tblCenter">` is actually closed in your _real_ code right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhdDt/) and I believe your issue is the use of `position:relative`.  I took those out (and the img backgrounds).
I'm not sure what design you are really going for as the `td,div` and id/class seem to be overkill.

Update

You don't set a width/height on the td with the imgs.  You'd also need to set some spacing between the td and inner div as well.  If the background img is 50x50, then your inner div needs a padding of 50px, plus or minus for style preference.

Also your example has no content = element of 0x0.

Comment: I wish I could show you a screen shot basically what I am building is a three row table that designed in photoshop. the <td> is supporting an background image of green check marks and red X's to show the difference between the services and price. The <div> tag is holding a grey line and is in place, however it looks to me like the  table that is holding the green check marks and red x's is collapsing. I have tried removing the position relative from the CSS and the table is still collapsed. From what I am seeing is firefox is not using the padding settings I made in my CSS

Comment: If you're div is empty, it collapses.  That's why the fiddle has "a" in each inner div.

Answer (score 0):

Per spec, relative positioning on table internal elements (rows, cells) has undefined behavior.  So if you're doing it, you're doing it at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help I figure out the issue, It was caused by firefox not adding the padding within the table cell space. I read some where that firefox has some issues with padding so what I did to trouble shoot the issue was add a red border around the entire table. which helped me see the width and height I next relaized that firefox was ignoring the padding setting, so I added the 8px of padding to the height of the table and removed all the padding. and as KnowHowSolutions suggested I reviewed the relative position and realized that once I adjusted the height the bottom positioning was wrong. after some adjustments and testing in all browsers everything worked out great. Thank you so much for taking the time to help.